# VB.NET How can I change cursor direction to right-to-left or left-to-right?

Tags: vb.net, cursor, richtextbox

I have a vb.net form that containing 2 richtextbox. The first richtextbox in English and the second in Arabic. How can I change the cursor direction so that its direction turns to the right when entering the Arab richtextbox and to the left when entering the English richtextbox??

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. If, in the Designer, you set one of the two controls to `[RichTextBox].RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No`, assuming the input language is Right-To-Left, you already have this behavior. Why would you change it when *entering the English richtextbox*? Isn't that somewhat weird for a User? What problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you mean changing the input language on enter a `RichTextBox` control? If that's what you are after, then you need to handle the `Enter` event of each `RTB` to switch the language through the [`InputLanguage`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.inputlanguage?view=net-5.0) class. The class has static properties to get the installed input languages, their cultures, the default and the current input languages.

Add `Enter` event handler for each `RTB` and handle them as follows:

**The English Language RTB**

```vb
Private Sub enRTB_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles enRTB.Enter

    Dim lang = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.
        Cast(Of InputLanguage).
        FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName = "en")

    If lang IsNot Nothing Then InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang
End Sub
```

**The Arabic Language RTB**

```vb
Private Sub arRTB_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles arRTB.Enter

    Dim lang = InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.
        Cast(Of InputLanguage).
        FirstOrDefault(Function(x) x.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName = "ar")

    If lang IsNot Nothing Then InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

All controls have a property named [`RightToLeft`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft) which is used to dictate the direction of text entry.

Here it is as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.righttoleft):

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether control's elements are aligned
> to support locales using right-to-left fonts.

In the case of your `RichTextBox`es, either set the property in the Properties window in the Form editor, or programatically like this:

```
EnglishRichTextBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.No
ArabicRichTextBox.RightToLeft = RightToLeft.Yes
```

If the `RichTextBox`es are dedicated for English or Arabic input, you should set them at design time.  There is a side effect of changing the value at runtime (in code), which is detailed in the docs:

> If the value of the `RightToLeft` property is changed at run time, only
> raw text without formatting is preserved.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work, the property RightToLeft is already set in the two richtextbox.
The idea in the solution is based on pressing the two keys (right ctrl + shift) through a code. their keycode is 16 and 17.