# Change Keyboard Layout in windows 11 is not working

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-11

I found a [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/5352992/How-do-I-change-keyboard-to-diffrent-culture#:%7E:text=To%20change%20the%20keyboard%20layout,Forms%20namespace) solution of changing keyboard layout. But it's not working in Windows 11.

Here's my code.

```cs
InputLanguage newLanguage = InputLanguage.FromCulture(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA"));
InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = newLanguage;
```

My keyboard layout in windows 11

[image: My keyboard layout in windows 11]

---

**Edit:**
With Win32 P/Invoke it work. But why the above code not working?

The working Win32/P-Invoke Code

```
LoadKeyboardLayout("0x0409", 1);    // English
LoadKeyboardLayout("00000401", 1);   // Arabic

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);
```

Comment: `InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage` calls  `ActivateKeyboardLayout()`: this only affects the current process. `LoadKeyboardLayout()` (Windows 8+), affects the entire System

Comment: I don't test it under Windows 7. So the best choice is LoadKeyboardLayout()?

Comment: Use "ar-EG" to match that keyboard layout.  The equivalent of the pinvoke code would be "ar", not actually sure that works.

Comment: The first code snippet does not work because the `ar-SA` is not installed in your system. You have the `ar-EG` variant. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67198691/14171304) for example to determine whether input language is installed.

Comment: Thanks to you all. I post an answer that collect .NET version and P/Invoke one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all people from above comments. The working code now is .NET :

```
     InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage =  
     InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages.Cast<InputLanguage> 
     ().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName == "ar");
```

This is preferred than P/Invoke things.

In case of anyone need P/Invoke that affect entire system:

```
            LoadKeyboardLayout("0x0409", 1);    // English
            LoadKeyboardLayout("00000401", 1);    // Arabic

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr LoadKeyboardLayout(string pwszKLID, uint Flags);
```

Answer (score 0):

For t As Integer = 1 To 10
If ((GetKeyboardLayout(0) And &HFFF0000)) <> &H4010000 Then
ActivateKeyboardLayout(HKL_NEXT, 0)             ' next keyboard
End If
Next

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).